# Implementing oauth, dynamic vs explicit type variables

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement `OAuth` in `asp.net-mvc` project following [these blog](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios) but I'm stuck with these two lines

```
var response = hc.GetAsync(userInfoUrl).Result;
dynamic userInfo = response.Content.ReadAsAsync().Result;
```

which gives me following errors

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpContent)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

If I change `userInfo` variable to explicit type would this implementation broke, and if not how can these be solved and why dynamic type is used?

Thanks.

Comment: is this error at runtime or on compile?